# onChange event on form emits output event only after blur

Tags: angular

In an app-form component there is a form. In a 'consumer component' (correct me if I'm wrong, not sure what to call it otherwise) I would like to enable or disable a button if that form is valid.

So to start with the consumer component:

**./app-thing.component.ts (consumer)**

```
// ...imports

@Component({
  selector: 'app-thing',
  template: `
    <app-form (isValidForm)="checkFormValidity($event)">
      <ng-container action>
        <button [disabled]="!buttonEnabled">Submit</button>
      </ng-container>
    </app-form>
  `,
})
export class AppThing {
  buttonEnabled = false;

  checkFormValidity(isValid: boolean) {
    this.buttonEnabled = isValid;
  }
}
```

Now to listen for events I am using the `onchange` event of the form:

**./app-form.components.ts (dynamic component)**

```
// ...imports

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form" (change)="formChange()">
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" formControlName="name" />
      </label>
      <ng-content select="[action]"></ng-content>
    </form>
  `
});
export class FormComponent {
  @Output()
  isValidForm = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  form = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
  });

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  formChange() {
    this.isValidForm.emit(this.form.valid);
  }
}
```

But now it only enables or disables the button if the user clicks somewhere on the page after an input change.

How do I change this to have it enable/disable the button when an input value changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-status-changes-4w98hz?file=src/app/app.component.html) is a working example.

We can use the `FormGroup` [`statusChanges`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#statusChanges) observable property to notify us when the status of our form changes.

```
// form.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: "app-form",
  templateUrl: "./form.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./form.component.css"]
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  public nameForm: FormGroup;

  @Output()
  public readonly formValid$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.buildForm();
    this.formValid$ = this.nameForm.statusChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      map(() => this.nameForm.valid),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  private buildForm() {
    this.nameForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

We assign it to the `formValid$` observable.

The `@Output` decorator is used pass the changes in state to our parent component.

We use [`debounceTime`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime) and [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged) to limit the number of events emitted.

```
// app.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public onChangeFormValidity(formValid: boolean) {
    console.log(formValid);
  }
}
```

We bind our `onChangeFormValidity` method to the `formValid$` output property.

```
// app.component.html
<app-form (formValid$)="onChangeFormValidity($event)"></app-form>
```

Comment: And is there a specific reason you're handling `this.formValid$ = ...` in the constructor? As opposed for example using it in `ngOnInit() { ... }`

Comment: It's only because we've used the [readonly modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#readonly-modifier), which means `formValid$` can only be read and can't be written to outside of the constructor. Not necessary, but it does communicate to other developers that we only want to initialise this property once. We could do the same for `nameForm`.